# How to do the following loop operations on dataframes in a single line in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to delete rows of a database according to certain conditions.

```
for index, row in df_A.iterrows():
   if name not in row["Name"].lower():
     df_A.drop(index, inplace= True)


for index, row in df_B.iterrows():
   if address != row["address"].split(":")[1]:
      df_B.drop(index, inplace= True)

for index, row in df_C.iterrows():
   name_given = name_dict[row["id"]]
   if name_given != name:
      df_C.drop(index, inplace= True)
```

The above code is working fine. But is there any shortcut way of doing these operations in pandas that do not use iterrows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df_A[df_A['name'].str.lower().str.contains(name)]
df_B[df_B['address'].str.split(':').str[1].eq(address)]
df_C[df_C['id'].map(name_dict).eq(name)]
```

Answer (score 0):

As u did not share sample data, could not test on your dataset but following worked for own dataset.

**This following lines could replace of your first blocks of your code out of three without using 'iterrows'**

```
df_A = df_A.fillna('0') #None/NAN cause error for 'series.str.contains' operation
df_A = df_A.drop(df_A[df_A['Name'].str.lower().str.contains(name)].index)
```